# Может ли быть эллиптическое предложение двусоставным?

Tags: синтаксис

Мы с соседом на заранее подготовленные позиции - в погреб.
Главный член предложения - мы с соседом.
Я так понимаю, что это двусоставное предложение с эллипсом сказуемого?
Неясен момент - это все-таки двусоставное предложение или нет? Потому что не получается квалифицировать его вид как односоставного, именное тут не подходит.

Спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Двусоставное неполное.

Answer (score 1):

Когда дают характеристику эллиптическому предложению, не указывают,односоставное оно или двусоставное. Это особый вид предложения, где отсутствие глагола является нормой. Оно близко к неполным, но не неполное, а именно эллиптическое. Но если это для школы, то в школьной грамматике говорят "двусоставное, эллиптически неполное". Если перед ним был определённый контекст(например, "каждый отправился на своё место. Мы с соседом..."), я бы не назвала такое предложение эллиптическим, оно больше похоже на контекстуально неполное с уточняющим обстоятельством.

Comment: Это для университета:) Контекст не дан. Требуется охарактеризовать, какое предложение - двусоставное/односоставное и полное/неполное (какое именно)

Comment: Тогда говорите, что неполное двусоставное, если такое задание. На присутствие сказуемого указывает наличие обстоятельства, так что оно не может быть односоставным. Двусоставное, контекстуально неполное. Хотя посмотрите в лекции, может, у вас называют эллиптически неполными.

Comment: Спасибо) У нас такие лекции, что приходится вас беспокоить:)